# how to create temp table in SQL using two tables with conditions

Tags: sql

I have two tables having two similar columns but i want new table by using above two tables.in that one table column having 1 to 30  numbers but another table have only 7 to 15 finally i want new column in new table having 7 to 15 true and remaing false.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And show us your current query attempt. BTW, which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join and case to solve this.
If after crossing your table with left join than you get

- **a.id b.id**
- 1   NULL
- 2   NULL
- 3   NULL
- 4   NULL
- 5   NULL
- 6   NULL
- 7   7
- 8   8
- ...
- 15 15
- 16 NULL
- 17 NULL
- ...
- 30 NULL

Then case b.id
when NULL THEN 'False'
else 'True'

I hope it helps.
It is my first entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to append a narrow table to a wider table, something like this...

```
 c01 | c02 | c03 | c04
-----+-----+-----+----
  T  |  T  |  T  | F
  T  |  F  |  T  | F

appended with...

 c01 | c02 
-----+-----
  T  |  F
  F  |  T

 giving....

 c01 | c02 | c03 | c04
-----+-----+-----+----
  T  |  T  |  T  | F
  T  |  F  |  T  | F
  T  |  F  |  F  | F
  F  |  T  |  F  | F
```

Then you can use `UNION ALL` and explicitly state the "dummy/default" values for the "missing" columns.

```
SELECT
  table_with_30_columns_of_variables.*
FROM
  table_with_30_columns_of_variables

UNION ALL

SELECT
  table_with_15_columns_of_variables.*,
  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
FROM
  table_with_15_columns_of_variables
```